# Perl GD:Graph y-intercept

Tags: perl, graph, gd

I am making a graph using GD:Graph in Perl, but I am unsure how to tell the line to start at a certain point. I have the slope, but it automatically starts at the point 0,0. I'm not sure where I can specify the y-intercept at the very least. I figure it has something to do with when I set up the data points,

```
    $data[0] = [@date];
    $data[1] = [@best_line];
```

Where data[0] will set up the x axis with the time and data[1] creates a line on the graph. If anyone has any insight on this that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a data point at x = 0:

```
@data = (
    [0, ...],
    [y-intercept, ...]
);
```